# Switch off color interpolation in PGFPLOTS

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I want to plot a heatmap-style diagram, where only the diagonal of a 2d-matrix has values. What i would expect is the plot to only contain color that represents values > 0 on the diagonal elements. However this is what i get:

[image]

Here's an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{heatmap.dat}
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 8.912886550287250076e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 9.175166561053226255e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 8.031786095794766211e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 9.125650835351171164e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 9.731804164301872673e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 8.030800439825510617e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 9.381443321189661955e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 9.573177461885088446e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 9.696479795497311427e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 9.189678833446063289e-01
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
        colorbar,
        y dir=reverse,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,]
      \addplot3[surf, shader=faceted] table {heatmap.dat};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Heatmap with PGFPLOTS}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can i switch off color-interpolation in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are looking for `shader=flat corner`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{heatmap.dat}
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 8.912886550287250076e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 9.175166561053226255e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 8.031786095794766211e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 9.125650835351171164e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 9.731804164301872673e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 8.030800439825510617e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 9.381443321189661955e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 9.573177461885088446e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 7.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 9.696479795497311427e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00

0.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00 9.189678833446063289e-01
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
        colorbar,
        y dir=reverse,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,]
      \addplot3[surf, shader=flat corner] table {heatmap.dat};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Heatmap with PGFPLOTS}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that exactly solves my issue. Thank you!

Comment: And welcome to the forum! Great to have you!